# "This page can't be reached" on Nuxt deployment

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js, digital-ocean, pm2

I'm trying to deploy a Nuxt App on Digital Ocean over Nginx with pm2.
When I go to the droplet IP I can see the Nginx welcome page but when I try to go to the IP:PORT of the Nuxt App it says:

```
This site can’t be reached
167.xx.xxx.xxx refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I have added this on sites-available/default file:

```
server {
   server_name domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:7200;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}
```

After this I checked for nginx status and restarted it.

Also, I added the service on pm2 with `pm2 start --name="webapp" npm -- start` and I can see it running correctly.

Even I have tried running directly `npm run start` command but I get the same result.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Please provide the exact error message you are seeing.

Comment: @EternalHour srry i just updated my question with the full error

Comment: if you go to your website and inspect the headers and then check the remote adress you  will see that you actually accessing the port 80, try it with `IP:80`

Comment: @Ifaruki if i go to the IP only, remote address shows IP:80, when i try IP:7200 i get request failed on network and headers aren't showed.

Answer (score 0):

```
  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
      root   /app;
      index  index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
  }
```